# Drawing a horizontal \rule through the middle of a line

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, rules, line, layout

How can I do something like `\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}`
but in a way that doesn't leave a big gap before it?
Currently it's kind of like `\bottomrule`, almost as if it skips a line. I want it to be more like `\midrule`, so it runs through the middle of where the text would usually be. It's not a `table` or `tabular` environment, so I can't really use those.

I'm using it to create strong visible separators between three distinct stanzas, paragraphs, or similar text blocks. I wouldn't usually do so, but it's a special situation.

Here's a comparison. Looking at them now, neither are really what I want. 
I want them to be a bit of each. So, usually theres a blank line between two paragraphs, right? Well i want to draw a line directly down the middle of that empty line. So the gap is symmetrically divided. I know it's a tiny thing, but with a word processor it would be relatively simple adjustment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{I'm a Heading}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    $$i^{(m)} = \frac{A_n}{\sum{q(uation)}}$$
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}
    \lipsum[2-2]
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}
    \lipsum[3-3]
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}
    \lipsum[4-4]
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{I'm a Heading}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    $$i^{(m)} = \frac{A_n}{\sum{q(uation)}}$$
    \noindent\toprule
    \lipsum[2-2]
    \noindent\midrule
    \lipsum[3-3]
    \noindent\midrule
    \lipsum[4-4]
    \noindent\bottomrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please make a MWE

Comment: There, you can have two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vcenter` to make sure the rule is perfectly centered on the center-line rather than the baseline and use an `\hrule` of height 0.25mm.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\separator{\par\vskip-\lastskip\noindent$\vcenter{\hfil\hrule height .25mm}$\par}

\begin{document}

Some paragraph ..
\separator
Some other paragraph ..

Now with \verb|enumerate|:
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item 
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\separator
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
\item First item 
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I think this might be it. what are the `$` for? Can you explain how that works please? Can I use it without defining a new command too?

Comment: Damn. Doesn't work after using `\enumerate`.

Comment: I've added an example with enumerate. `enumerate` adds space above and below itself, to remove the space above use `[topsep=0pt]` after loading the `enumitem` package and to remove the space below, add `\vskip-\lastskip` to the macro you created.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `6pt` and `-7pt` to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myline{\par\noindent\rule[6pt]{\linewidth}{0.25mm}\vspace{-7pt}\par}
\begin{document}
This(g)

\myline
That

\myline

The other
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I use currently. I should have mentioned that. The problem is it seems kind of hacky and it causes problems when rearranging a final document, especially where floats are concerned. It's a real nightmare. Also, you kind of have to adjust it and recompile until you get it right. Plus it's hard to get the dimensions perfect and all that.

Comment: @tjt263 Without an MWE on your part, it is awful difficult to figure that out.